# Apache 2.4: PHP files are not being sent to the browser

Tags: php, apache

I'm setting up a new site locally on a Windows machine for testing. In the document root, if I have an `index.html` it is served to the browser without problem. If I rename it `index.php`, the browser receives nothing. No error is raised server-side. I'm trying to understand why.

**Vhosts**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\websites\learn"
    ServerName learn.loc

    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace2

    #PHP SETTINGS   
    php_value auto_prepend_file "C:\websites\learn\noop.php"
    php_value open_basedir "C:\websites\learn"

    <Directory "C:\websites\learn">    
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>   

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the `.htaccess` file that resides in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
#point to javascript learning project
RewriteRule ^js   /javascript
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)   /javascript/$1
```

Here is the `mod_rewrite` log generated when I load `learn.loc/javascript` (this folder has an `index.php` file)

```
[initial] [perdir C:/websites/learn/] pass through C:/websites/learn/javascript/
[subreq] [perdir C:/websites/learn/] pass through C:/websites/learn/javascript/index.html
[subreq] [perdir C:/websites/learn/] pass through C:/websites/learn/javascript/index.htm
[subreq] [perdir C:/websites/learn/] pass through C:/websites/learn/javascript/index.php
```

Nothing is added to Apache or PHP error log; The browser itself receives `status code 200`, along with the following response headers

```
Date:           "..."
Server:         "Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) PHP/5.6.23"
X-Powered-By:   "PHP/5.6.23"
Content-Length: "0"
Keep-Alive:     "timeout=5, max=100"
Connection:     "Keep-Alive"
Content-Type:   "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

The response body is an empty string. Like I said, if I rename the file to `index.html` the content (vanilla html file) is shown. What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. That was just me being careless.  The problem was with this line from Vhosts config:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "C:\websites\learn\noop.php"
```

More specifically, what was supposed to be a noop was really an execution killer.

**noop.php**

```
<?php
exit; // <- exits not just this script but all of PHP and returns to the browser
```

Once I removed the 2nd line, things were back in order. This also explains why renaming `index.php` to `index.html` got things working: it took PHP out of the loop entirely.